# How to debug a xamarin app in Emulator

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin. I develop an app and deployed it on VS Emulator for android but on clicking of a button, the app is getting crashed. Please let me know the step which I can take to attach my app to VS so That I can figure out the cause of crashing the app

Comment: Are you running it in debug mode? Did you set breakpoints? Are you running your simulator over the network or local?

Comment: I am running it on debug mode an also set the breakpoints. Simulator is on the same machine as well but somehow I the code is not getting attached.

Comment: Clean your solution, add break points, build the solution, remove the existing app from simulator and then try again.@KumarGaurav

Answer (score 0):

[Please see this Xamarin documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/) to undestand how you can debug your xamarin app in Emulator.

There are two standard Emulators that you can use, one is Android SDK Emulator which is the default emulator that is provided with the Andorid SDK and the other one is Visual Studio Android Emulator which is a Visual Studio 2015 built in Android emulator. Alternatively, you can use [Gorilla Player](http://gorillaplayer.com/).